# Question about a oscillatory integrals on manifold

Tags: cv.complex-variables, harmonic-analysis, dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact oriented Riemannian manifold without boundary.

Set $f(x)=a(x)+\sqrt{-1}b(x)$ be a complex-valued function on $M$,
where $a(x),b(x)$ are real-valued function on $M$.

Then, how to compute the Oscillatory integrals below?
$$I(t)=\int_{M}e^{-\sqrt{-1}tf(x)}dv=\int_{M}e^{tb(x)}e^{-\sqrt{-1}ta(x)}dv$$
where $dv$ be a smooth density on $M$.

Especially, I am interested in discussing the asymptotic behaviour
of $I(t)$ when $t\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: If you look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88640/asymptotic-behaviour-of-int-fta-cosatdt/90688#90688, you'll realize that the question you ask is far too general to have a good answer. :(